# Trouble getting #each to work in Handlebars.js for my object

Tags: typescript, handlebars.js

With the following typescript objects:

```
class LinkItem {
    public LinkText: string;
    public LinkUrl: string;
}

class Link {
    public DisplayText: string;
    public LinkItems: Array<LinkItem>;

    constructor() {
        this.LinkItems = new Array<LinkItem>();
    }
}

class LinksObject {
    public Links: Array<Link>;

    constructor() {
        this.Links = new Array<Link>();
    }
}
```

what is the correct HandleBars.js syntax to iterate the properties in LinksObject to create a table like:

[image]

I have tried various combinations of . this etc. in the #each syntax and nothing works as expected.

```
<script id="entry-template-family-links" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
        <tbody>
            {{#each .}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{this}} a {{this.DisplayText}} b  {{DisplayText}} c {{this.LinkText}} d {{LinkText}}</td>
                <td>
                    <span>
                        {{#each this.LinkItems}}
                        <a target="_blank" href="{{this.LinkUrl}}">{{this.LinkText}}</a>
                        {{/each}}
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction as I am clearly missing something obvious?

Comment: "nothing works as expected" - what behaviour are you seeing? What do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting to be able to create the table as indicated by my image. Instead I am not getting any rows or data at all in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you are passing the object down to handlebars, but have you tried this?

```
{{#each Link}}
```

Comment: I went back to how I was returning the object and passed that value viz {{#each LinksList.Links}}. and then I could use {{this.Link}}